# Clean way of dealing with collections of different implementations of Abstract classes?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, implementation

I have a few Abstract classes that have the core functionality of some `UserControls` in my project.  I also have two separate implementations both deriving from the Abstract classes; lets call them `AbstractImpl1` and `AbstractImpl2.`   In addition, I have `Collections` of the Abstract `UserControls` that I iterate through in several places.

The issue I'm having is `InvalidCastExceptions` - I need to iterate through the implementations rather than the abstact UserControls to get to certain properties (visual).  Is there a clean way of dealing with this other than doing a `try/catch`?

**Example:**

In my project I have Abstract classes: `AbsUserControl`
Then I have two separate implementations of them: `AbstractImpl1` and `AbstractImpl2`

In my main form I have `ObservableCollection<AbsUserControl> absControlCollection` and then iterating through items I do `foreach(AbstractImpl1 userControl in absControlCollection)` to be able to access the visual aspects.  The issue is that `ObservableCollection<AbsUserControl> absControlCollection` could either be comprised of `AbstractImpl1` or `AbstractImpl2` objects.

Is there a clean way of dealing with this?  Right now, every place I iterate through the objects in `absControlCollection` I surround it with a `try/catch` block, trying to iterate through `AbstractImpl1` objects then catching an `InvalidCastException` and proceeding with iterating through `AbstractImpl2` objects.

Let me know if any more information is needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the collection is _all_ `Impl1` or _all_ `Impl2`, never a mixture?

Comment: @Rawling Right now the collections are either `Impl1` or `Impl2`, but it is possible that I would want a mixed collection later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to `OfType`; casting without exceptions:

```
foreach(AbsUserControl control in absControlCollection)
{
    if(control is AbstractImpl1)
    {
        AbstractImpl1 i1 = (AbstractImpl1)control;
        DoStuff(i1);
    }
    if(control is AbstractImpl2)
    {
        AbstractImpl2 i2 = (AbstractImpl2)control;
        DoOtherStuff(i2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Even though Rawling's answers is 'cleaner' this actually meets my needs better - a lot of the logic in the `foreach()` loops are common between the two implementations, so it makes more sense for me to check which implementation it is within the `foreach()`, do the specific logic, then continue with the common logic rather than having a separate `foreach()` loop which would force me to repeat logic.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to do the filtering for you:

```
foreach(AbstractImpl1 userControl in
    absControlCollection.OfType<AbstractImpl1>())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very clean implementation, but @SebastianNegraszus's solution actually meets my specific needs better

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably go for his solution myself too :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's **[`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)** method to safely filter out only the concrete implementation that you are interested in. Your `foreach` would then look like:

```
foreach(var userControl in abcControlCollection.OfType<AbstractImpl1>())
{
    /* ... */
}
```